# Android map view pan over detection

Tags: android, events, dictionary, android-mapview

I am using android `MapView`

I want to trigger some event when map view is panned if user is panning through it should get triggered at the end of set of panning

I need to make a http call to pull some data based on the map view user has currently at the end of panning that is why I need to listen to that panning end event

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to get such events. But you can try [MapView Overlay Manager](https://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/) to listen to some gestures. Or write your own class extends from MapView to catch touch events from user.

EDIT:

For extending a Mapview, override the onTouchEvent method.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        GeoPoint centerGeoPoint = this.getMapCenter();
        if (currentCenter == null || 
                (currentCenter.getLatitudeE6() != centerGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()) ||
                (currentCenter.getLongitudeE6() != centerGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()) ) {
            firePanEvent(currentCenter, this.getMapCenter());
        }
        currentCenter = this.getMapCenter();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: if I extend MapView how can I get handle to track more touch events ?

Comment: +1 I will implement this and I will accept it shortly, Thanks

Comment: if you also want to answer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196027/android-highlighting-certain-dates-on-calendar-view