# Highlighting certain dates on Android CalendarView

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I am using Android's `CalendarView` and I need to highlight some dates.  I can't find any methods to do that.  Is there anything available?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to highlight a specific date, then you can call setDate().

If you want to highlight multiple dates, there are no simple method to do that. You should write your own calendar view.